# Send variable as PDF file with requests.post in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a PDF file as a bytes variable in python 
 `file = b'%PDF-1.4\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Title (\xfe\xff)\n/Creator (\xfe\xff)...R\n>>\nstartxref\n63581\n%%EOF\n'`

And I want to send this file via requests.post
`upload_file_request = requests.post(url, files={'file' : open(file, 'rb')}, headers=headers_json)`

But I get encoding errors such as `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 28: invalid start by` and others. What is the right way to do this?

**UPDATE** 
Okay,so what I did was use `tempfile` to save my variable and then read it from there

```
    file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    file_name = file.name
    file.write(doc_file)
    file.seek(0)

    upload_passport_file_request = requests.post(url,
                 files={"file": ("PDF", open(file_name, 'rb'), "application/pdf")},
                 headers=headers_turnkey)
   
    file.close()
    os.unlink(file_name)
```

Not the most beautiful solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

You are posting a file with the name "file". That is your PDF content is the file name. You need to post data.

```
upload_file_request = requests.post(url, data=file)
```

See here how to do it right: [https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_post.asp#:~:text=%20Python%20Requests%20post%20%28%29%20Method%20%201,certain%20HTTP%20authentication.%20A%20String%20or...%20More%20](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_post.asp#:%7E:text=%20Python%20Requests%20post%20%28%29%20Method%20%201,certain%20HTTP%20authentication.%20A%20String%20or...%20More%20)

https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/showpython.asp?filename=demo_requests_post

Comment: Yeah, I would be sending it as data if I can. The problem is that I am sending it to a third party API and they require me to send it as a file, not as data